# How to change this statement in switch

Tags: c++

```
if (year == 9 || year == 10) {
    dividend = investment * 7.5;
}
else if (year == 7 || year == 8) {
    dividend = investment * 6.5;
}
else if (year == 5 || year == 6){
    dividend = investment * 5.5;
}
else  {
    dividend = investment * 3.5;
}

cout << "The dividend is RM " << dividend << endl;
```

Comment: You need to provide some background on what ever the source code is and include an actual question to go along with the posted source code.

Comment: Did you mean "how to change this statement into a switch-case"? If so, I would maybe recommend trying to do it first and then asking a specific question if you run into trouble doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this isn't a homework assignment, but...

```
switch (year) {
  case 9:
  case 10:
    dividend = investment * 7.5;
    break;
  case 7:
  case 8:
    dividend = investment * 6.5;
    break;
  ...
}
cout << “The dividend is RM “ << dividend << endl;
```

The idea is that case statements can "fall through" unless you call "break".  Effectively creating an "or" condition.

You can read more here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm

Comment: You should also add `default` case to match `else {...}` statement.

Comment: I didn't want to give the *entire* answer ... but yes, in retrospect I probably should have added "default", too ;)